# Mysql retrieve all rows with limit

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to retrieve all rows of a particular user with limit 0,x..

So i just want to ask is there any way to retrieve all rows in mysql without calling a method which returns count(id) of x& without making an overload of existing function which does not have limit at all in query & withour string.Relace() functionality.

As internally mysql is might using this when we check show all check Box then all rows of taht table are displayed

Comment: You might want to give an example of your intended result.

Comment: @Daniel: i wnat to display first time 100 things of user when page load so Limit help me there & want to show all things of him/her when user visit visit his home page I can do it with fucntion overload/string.replace() but i cnat make new function/ modify existing one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple solution is sending int's max range to method i.e 2147483647 as it is same in both mysql & c# (4 bytes) can use int.MaxValue .

see references:

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/numeric-types.html
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types.

Answer (score 11):

To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

This can be found in mysql developers documentation.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I would've called this an ugly hack, but it does seem to be the accepted/documented way to do this.

Comment: php max int may less then 18446744073709551615 so you should use the PHP_INT_MAX predefined value to avoid overflows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve all rows, you just don't use the LIMIT clause..

Comment: he said: "I want to retrieve all rows of a particular user with limit 0,x.."

Comment: @deepesh khatri - then I don't get why you want to use `LIMIT`, if you don't want to `LIMIT` anything

Comment: @Bozho: i wnat to display first time 100 things of user when page load so Limit help me there & want to show all things of him/her when user visit visit his home page I can do it with fucntion overload/string.replace() but i cnat make new function/ modify existing one. Got it

Comment: You mean you want to break all of the user's rows into multiple pages, so first visit they only see the first 100 rows, then they can click to page 2 and get rows 101 through 200, etc...?

That's exactly what LIMIT is designed for. Retrieving all the relevant rows in the database and then filtering in the program is a waste of bandwidth/cpu cycles.

Comment: @Bozho: i got the solution see it.

Comment: you are not answering the question

Comment: Fetching all rows even though `LIMIT` is given is useful when dealing with libraries which support 'prepared statements' which permit filling it values, but not entire clauses, like `SELECT title FROM questions WHERE user LIKE ? LIMIT 0,?` (and the `?` characters are replaced by the API with user-provided values).

Answer (score 1):

**WHY ONE MIGHT NEED THIS**:

One Scenario which one might want to use this is while doing server side pagination.

For example, if one wants to retrieve a specific number of results per page: 
he may dynamically write the query as follows:

```
  'select * from users limit '+ perPage`
```

But what should `perPage` be if he wants all results?

**A SIMPLE SOLUTION**:

`limit = (perPage=='x')?'':'limit'+perPage`

now write the query as `'select * from users' + limit`. 
and If you want all the results, make sure value of perPage is 'x'.